# Stabebaseline_contrib producing NAN values during training in MaskablePPO

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

During training, nan values are produced by the algorithm. These nan values are produced in the neural network. I found several ideas in issues that were proposed, I tried all of them but still got the error. The solutions were: changing np.float64 to np.float32, which doesn't work. Using use_expln=True, which MaskablePPO doesn't have. I also changed the model's parameter such as gamma, but still got the same error. Tried to decrease learning rate that again faced the error

```
class custom(gym.Env):
.
.
.
env = custom()
def mask_fn(env: gym.Env) -> List[bool]:
    return env.valid_action_mask()
env = ActionMasker(env, mask_fn)
model = MaskablePPO(MaskableActorCriticPolicy, env, gamma=0.001, verbose=0)
checkpoint_callback = CheckpointCallback(save_freq=10000, save_path='logs',
                                         name_prefix='rl_model')
model.learn(500000, callback=checkpoint_callback)
model.save("JOM")
```

the error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-abee064644f3> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 checkpoint_callback = CheckpointCallback(save_freq=10000, save_path='logs',
      2                                          name_prefix='rl_model')
----> 3 model.learn(500000, callback=checkpoint_callback)
      4 model.save("JOM")

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/ppo_mask/ppo_mask.py in learn(self, total_timesteps, callback, log_interval, tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps, use_masking, progress_bar)
    545                 self.logger.dump(step=self.num_timesteps)
    546 
--> 547             self.train()
    548 
    549         callback.on_training_end()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/ppo_mask/ppo_mask.py in train(self)
    410                     actions = rollout_data.actions.long().flatten()
    411 
--> 412                 values, log_prob, entropy = self.policy.evaluate_actions(
    413                     rollout_data.observations,
    414                     actions,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/policies.py in evaluate_actions(self, obs, actions, action_masks)
    331             latent_vf = self.mlp_extractor.forward_critic(vf_features)
    332 
--> 333         distribution = self._get_action_dist_from_latent(latent_pi)
    334         if action_masks is not None:
    335             distribution.apply_masking(action_masks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/policies.py in _get_action_dist_from_latent(self, latent_pi)
    244         """
    245         action_logits = self.action_net(latent_pi)
--> 246         return self.action_dist.proba_distribution(action_logits=action_logits)
    247 
    248     def _predict(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/distributions.py in proba_distribution(self, action_logits)
    192         reshaped_logits = action_logits.view(-1, sum(self.action_dims))
    193 
--> 194         self.distributions = [
    195             MaskableCategorical(logits=split) for split in th.split(reshaped_logits, tuple(self.action_dims), dim=1)
    196         ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/distributions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    193 
    194         self.distributions = [
--> 195             MaskableCategorical(logits=split) for split in th.split(reshaped_logits, tuple(self.action_dims), dim=1)
    196         ]
    197         return self

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sb3_contrib/common/maskable/distributions.py in __init__(self, probs, logits, validate_args, masks)
     40     ):
     41         self.masks: Optional[th.Tensor] = None
---> 42         super().__init__(probs, logits, validate_args)
     43         self._original_logits = self.logits
     44         self.apply_masking(masks)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributions/categorical.py in __init__(self, probs, logits, validate_args)
     68             self._param.size()[:-1] if self._param.ndimension() > 1 else torch.Size()
     69         )
---> 70         super().__init__(batch_shape, validate_args=validate_args)
     71 
     72     def expand(self, batch_shape, _instance=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributions/distribution.py in __init__(self, batch_shape, event_shape, validate_args)
     66                 valid = constraint.check(value)
     67                 if not valid.all():
---> 68                     raise ValueError(
     69                         f"Expected parameter {param} "
     70                         f"({type(value).__name__} of shape {tuple(value.shape)}) "

ValueError: Expected parameter logits (Tensor of shape (64, 2)) of distribution MaskableCategorical(logits: torch.Size([64, 2])) to satisfy the constraint IndependentConstraint(Real(), 1), but found invalid values:
tensor([[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
```

During training, nan values are produced by the algorithm. These nan values are produced in the neural network. I found several ideas in issues that were proposed, I tried all of them but still got the error. The solutions were: changing np.float64 to np.float32, which doesn't work. Using use_expln=True, which MaskablePPO doesn't have. I also changed the model's parameter such as gamma, but still got the same error. Tried to decrease learning rate that again faced the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to normalize your data inputs and out puts. can you give me more details about the data that you are using and the preprossesing you did before training.

Comment: I guess the package itself normalizes the input, which is the environment state. My state is a numpy array of 42 numbers which the first of them is integer numbers, and the rest are numbers between 0 and 1.